# npm ERR! on npm install

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install

> ```
> C:\Users\Mayur Saner\pmrm>npm install
> npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
> npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
> npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/@fortawesome%2ffontawesome-free failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND proxy.company.com
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> npm ERR! network
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mayur Saner\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-18T09_56_28_976Z-debug-log
> ```

Getting this error on npm install from last week, before that it was working fine. What might have happened now ?

Comment: check your internet connection~

Comment: yes everything is fine, also tried proxy

Comment: seems like you are using proxy on your network. verify it

Comment: @MayurSaner - Please read the reasons for why [you should not post code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question#answer-285557) - Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the problem seems to be with proxy or network configuration;
try clearing proxy using:

```
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy

npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy

set HTTP_PROXY=null
set HTTPS_PROXY=null
```

Comment: Now getting this : npm ERR! Cannot read property 'startsWith' of null